# Word for person who doesn't wake up easily

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who doesn't wake up easily from a noise or a touch? I just want to know a word that defines what I am asking for.

Comment: A *heavy sleeper*.

Comment: Do you want a noun or an adjective, or is either OK? Please read the guidance for asking "[single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)" and edit your question accordingly to make sure it has all of the required information, such as the context where you want to use this word and any research you have already done.

Comment: [*comatose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma) but used in a figurative sense. Otherwise the person sleeps "like a log", which suggests someone who never wakes up during the night.

Comment: Could you not provide a sentence showing how this word, or phrase would be used? This is one of those questions which could attract a lot of attention if it showed a little more thought.

Comment: @DanBron **Deep sleeper**, also

Comment: The person is a *heavy*, *deep*, or *sound* sleeper.  (I'd tend to use *sound*.)

Answer (score 1):

- sleepyhead
- Lie-abed
- a Rip Van Winkle

–– all meaning fond of deep and protracted sleep.

Comment: A "sleepyhead" to me is someone who is currently awake but sleepy, and prone to sleeping, not someone who is necessarily difficult to wake.

Comment: Not that.use any std.dictionary.:you sleepyhead! When would you get up! We would be at the prayer hall by this time.

Answer (score 0):

Quite informal but someone might be described as **"out"**, meaning "deeply asleep".  eg

*"Did you wake him up?"  "No, he's **out**, man."*

Obviously "out" has many meanings and so this usage is very context dependent.  Still, it's a single word.

EDIT:  this obviously isn't a **characteristic**, ie it's an adjective not a noun.  OP, it's still not quite clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiomatic phrase *[sleep the sleep of the dead](http://www.oneworldofenglish.com/english_idioms/idioms_S/sleep_the_sleep_of_the_dead.htm)* that is often used.

> To sleep well without being disturbed

*oneworldofenglish.com*

And *[dead to the world](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dead-to-the-world)*

> (informal) Fast asleep.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The phrase *dead sleep* is also used.

If you want to be poetic, *[in the arms of Morpheus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+like+a+log)*, suggesting a deep sleep as if induced by a narcotic.

*The Free Dictionary*